# Capybara.current_driver = :chrome versus :selenium_chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

what are the advantages/pros/cons of using

```
Capybara.current_driver = :chrome
```

versus using

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

To give a bit more context, I'm using capybara in a standalone ruby script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just names that can be used to identify specific driver configurations so it all depends on what is registered as `:chrome` and `:selenium_chrome`.  The latest Capybara (2.15.1) release provides a default registration for `:selenium_chrome` which is defined as

```
# Configure selenium-webdriver to use chrome as the browser
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

but that can be redefined in your code. There is no gem, that I know of, that provides a default registration of `:chrome` so if that's currently valid it would most likely be defined in your code (search for `register_driver`).

Comment: your name sounded familiar, turns out  im a fan of your work